# What is the best way to convert 300 words to vector graphics (svg) on Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have 300 words written in Arabic language and would like to convert them to SVG file type in Illustrator, So what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text can beconverted to vector art by using the “create outlines” tool:

1. Choose the Selection Tool (shortcut = “V”)
2. Select your text (underlined in text format).
3. Select the “Type” menu, then select “Create Outlines” (Mac shortcut = Shift/Command/O, PC shortcut = Shift/Control/O).
4. Your text should now be outlined in vector format.